# Copy worksheet from one workbook and paste to another

Tags: excel, vba

In my macro, I have the user open a workbook due to the name changing every month. I need the first worksheet on this now open workbook to copy and then paste into my original workbook.

I've been trying the below:

```
ActiveSheet.Copy After:=Workbooks("LTD_LIFE_Macro.xls").Sheets("instructions")
```

but keep getting an error message.

Comment: Can you [edit] your question with your current code?

Comment: what is the error you get ?

Comment: Your line looks fine to me

Comment: I get a "Run-Time Error '9':
Subscript out of range